# How to get the correct min and max values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8341c
and from those records my expected  output  its the following

```
Name|MinCost |MaxCost | Open | Close | Date
ABC |13.6    | 15.3   | 14.1 | 14.2  | 2015-12-02
DEF |93.2    | 96.3   | 93.7 | 95.4  | 2015-12-02 
ABC |15.1    | 15.6   | 15.1 | 15.2  | 2015-12-03
DEF |97.2    | 97.7   | 97.7 | 97.7  | 2015-12-03
```

Right now i have done this

```
SELECT t1.name as 'Name',t1.min as 'MinCost',t1.max as 'MaxCost',t2.open ,t3.close,t1.times as 'Date'
  FROM(
        select name, max(cost) as 'max',min(cost) as 'min', date(time) as 'times'  
        from providers 
        group by  times,name 
        order by times
   ) AS t1
   JOIN (
     select name,cost as 'open',  time  
     from providers 
     where TIME(time) = '00:00:00'   
     group by time,name
     order by time
   ) as t2 on t1.name=t2.name
   JOIN (
       select name,cost as 'close', time  
       from providers 
       where TIME(time) = '23:59:59'   
       group by time,name
       order by time
   ) as t3 on t2.name=t3.name 
   GROUP BY t1.times,t1.name
   ORDER BY t1.times,t1.name
```

which gives me the following output

```
| Name | MinCost | MaxCost | open | close |       Date |
|------|---------|---------|------|-------|------------|
|  ABC |    13.6 |    15.3 | 14.1 |  14.2 | 2015-12-02 |
|  DEF |    93.2 |    96.3 | 97.7 |  95.4 | 2015-12-02 |
|  ABC |    15.1 |    15.6 | 14.1 |  14.2 | 2015-12-03 |
|  DEF |    97.2 |    97.7 | 97.7 |  95.4 | 2015-12-03 |
```

what do i need to correct the query?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Could you provide the expected output of your query?

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo, my expected output its at the beginning of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select
  d.name, d.min_cost, d.max_cost,
  o.cost as open,
  c.cost as close,
  d.d as date
from (
  select
    name,
    min(cost) as min_cost,
    max(cost) as max_cost,
    min(time) as open_time,
    max(time) as close_time,
    date(time) as d
  from providers
  group by name, date(time)
) d
join providers o on o.name = d.name and o.time = d.open_time
join providers c on c.name = d.name and c.time = d.close_time
order by d.d, d.name
```

Result:

```
name  min_cost  max_cost  open  close  date
----  --------  --------  ----  -----  ----------
ABC       13.6      15.3  14.1   14.2  2015-12-02
DEF       93.2      96.3  93.7   95.4  2015-12-02
ABC       15.1      15.6  15.1   15.2  2015-12-03
DEF       97.2      97.7  97.7   97.4  2015-12-03
```

Please note that your expected result is a little bit wrong on the last row, since the open price is `97.7`.

Comment: Thank You!, Elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Since your name is not unique, you need to add the `time` in the join `on` clause so you get a unique value with `name` and `time`.

Below query should work, [Demo on your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8341c/15) to get the expected output

```
  SELECT t1.name as 'Name',t1.min as 'MinCost',t1.max as 'MaxCost',t2.open ,t3.close,t1.times as 'Date'
  FROM(
        select name, max(cost) as 'max',min(cost) as 'min', date(time) as 'times'  
        from providers 
        group by  times,name 
        order by times
   ) AS t1
   JOIN (
     select name,cost as 'open',  date(time) as 'times' 
     from providers 
     where TIME(time) = '00:00:00'   
     group by time,name
     order by time
   ) as t2 on t1.name=t2.name and t1.times = t2.times
   JOIN (
       select name,cost as 'close', date(time) as 'times' 
       from providers 
       where TIME(time) = '23:59:59'   
       group by time,name
       order by time
   ) as t3 on t2.name=t3.name  and t2.times = t3.times
   GROUP BY t1.times,t1.name
   ORDER BY t1.times,t1.name
```

Comment: This works well too!, thank you for answering! really apreciate it